# Android Shared Preferences Won't Save

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying out shared preferences, but I can't get my changes to save persistently.

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
String lastPlayerPref = "LAST_PLAYER";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
    String lastPlayer = prefs.getString(lastPlayerPref, "test");
    System.err.println(lastPlayer);  //always outputs "test" no matter what I do

    prefsEditor.putString(lastPlayerPref, "me");
    prefsEditor.commit();

    ...
}
```

When I run this initially, I would expect the output "test". When I run it after that, I expect it to output "me". But it always outputs "test". Isn't that argument just a default in the event that no preference has been saved?

Sorry for the confusion. Thanks!

Comment: What is `lastPlayerPref`? Does it ever change?

Comment: Sorry - forgot to show the variable. No, it doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, I close and re-open. I'm working in an emulator. And no, I'm not rebuilding in between.

Comment: Do you close the emulator or just the app?

Comment: Just the app. Actually, I've done both in the process of testing, but it should work when I close only the app, I think.

Comment: Eclipse has a "wipe user data on start" option for emulators, I wanted to make sure that wasn't a factor... You code works on my device, do you use `prefsEditor` anywhere else?

Comment: OK. Thanks for trying it out. Must be the emulator. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add **.putString(lastPlayerPref, "player1");**

```
prefs = ProgressBarActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
prefsEditor = prefs.edit().putString(lastPlayerPref, "player1");
prefsEditor.commit();

String lastPlayer = prefs.getString(lastPlayerPref, "test");
System.err.println(lastPlayer);

prefsEditor = prefs.edit().putString(lastPlayerPref, "player2");
prefsEditor.commit();

lastPlayer = prefs.getString(lastPlayerPref, "test");
System.err.println(lastPlayer);
```

if you try above you will see it will change

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see from my code, I do have a .putString command there. Are you thinking that I did that incorrectly?

Comment: that codes works for me on real device but i saw your comment now, you are working on emulator. I didnt try on emulator.